# How to get this simple one-way binding with knockout to work?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am learning knockout and this is my first ever example of it, so please be gentle.

I just want a one-way binding from the model to the textboxes, i.e, whatever is in the model must be displayed in the text boxes. I do not want to create observables yet.

Here is what I have, but when I run this code, the text boxes do not contain the model values, and the console reports an error:

> `TypeError: c is null`

Here is my code:

**1.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='1.js'></script>
    </head>

    <form id = "frm" name = "frm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Your friend's basic information</legend>

            <div>
                <label for = "FirstName">First Name</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "FirstName" id = "txtFirstName" data-bind = "value: friend.firstName" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for = "LastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "LastName" id = "txtLastName" data-bind = "value: friend.lastName" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
</html>
```

**1.js**

```
var model = 
{
    friend : 
    {
        firstName : 'Sathyaish',
        lastName : 'Chakravarthy'
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

It looks like knockout isn't able to bind a nested property. Since the property I am binding to isn't directly a member of the `model` object, but it is instead nested inside `model.friend`, it isn't able to bind it.

Surely it can't be that I cannot have a hierarchical model and that I can only bind if the properties are top-level members of the `model` object?

I am most likely doing something wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass `rootElement` to apply bindings, it's going to use `window.document.body`. However, if you script is loaded in `head` section, the `body` is not available at that moment. So you need to move your `1.js` loading inside the body like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js'></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <form id = "frm" name = "frm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Your friend's basic information</legend>

            <div>
                <label for = "FirstName">First Name</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "FirstName" id = "txtFirstName" data-bind = "value: friend.firstName" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for = "LastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "LastName" id = "txtLastName" data-bind = "value: friend.lastName" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='1.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks much. 4 minutes before the green checkie. :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, you're welcome. Should be able to accept it now)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use mapping library to do that.
When you use nested properties like a class you need to use mapping.
check it out: [Plugin Knockout Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Your code wil be some like that:

```
var viewModel = function () {
var _vm = null,

init = function () {

    _vm = {
      friend : ko.mapping.fromJS({
        firstName : 'Sathyaish',
        lastName : 'Chakravarthy'
        }),
        change: function(){
        _vm.friend.firstName('first name changed');
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(_vm, $('#frm').get(0));
}

return {
    init: init
}
```

}();

i have that scenario all the time.
I put in JSFIDDLE [check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/pqxys9aj/4/)

Comment: It works just fine without that plug-in for me. I am hoping a serious framework wouldn't be stumped by model hierarchies.

Comment: I think you may have a point. I hit a roadblock in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/40325541/303685) which may require mapping, but I am not sure.

Comment: Hi! Try to use the mapping plugin like i said and the way you are trying to modify the properties. It needs to be in parenteses: property("value")