# How to bind a model to knockout if the model is not a top-level object?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am learning knockout.js. I did [one example earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40319663/303685), which I am trying to modify in two ways:

1. I organized the code to minimize global scope so there's just one top-level object inside the `window` object and I put everything including my model in there.
2. I wanted to see if the `text:` binding changes the view when the model changes if the model is not an observable. For a finer elaboration of this idea, please see the comments in the HTML code below.

However, when I run this bit of code, I get a `ReferenceError: friend is not defined.`

I am assuming it is because of the fact that my `model` object is no longer a top-level member of the `window` object.

Is it possible to have a model hierarchy like this and have it work with knockout?

**1a.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
    </head>

    <!-- The purpose of this program is to find out whether just a 
        text: binding also changes the display / view if the model changes.
        Meaning if I explicitly do not create an observable out of a model property
        and use only a text: binding, does the property still behave like an observable?

        To do this, I am using the same code as 1.html and 1.js, 
        except for one change. I am adding another set of textboxes
        in which I will type in a new first name and last name.
        Then, I will click the "Update Name" button
        in whose listener, I will update the model properties friend.firstName
        and friend.lastName.

        Then, I'd like to see if the text box values for txtFirstName and txtLastName
        change.
        -->
    <body>

        <form id = "frm" name = "frm">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your friend's basic information:</legend>

                <div>
                    <label for = "FirstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "FirstName" id = "txtFirstName" data-bind = "value: friend.firstName" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for = "LastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "LastName" id = "txtLastName" data-bind = "value: friend.lastName" />
                </div>


                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>New Information:</legend>

                        <div>
                            <label for = "NewFirstName">New Value for First Name</label>
                            <input type = "text" name = "NewFirstName" id = "txtNewFirstName" />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label for = "NewLastName">New Value for Last Name</label>
                            <input type = "text" name = "NewLastName" id = "txtNewLastName" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                <div>
                    <input type = "button" value = "Update Name" id = "btnUpdateName" name = "Save" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </form>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='1a.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**1a.js**

```
var ThisDocument = function()
{
    this.model = 
    {
        friend : 
        {
            firstName : 'Sathyaish',
            lastName : 'Chakravarthy'
        }
    };

    this.init = function()
    {
        wire(window, "load", wireElementHandlers);
    };

    function wire(element, eventName, listener)
    {
        var ie = document.all ? true : false;

        if (!element) throw new Error("Element " + element + " not found.");

        if (ie)
        {
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, listener);
        }
        else
        {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, listener, false);
        }
    };


    function wireElementHandlers()
    {
        var btnUpdateName = document.getElementById('btnUpdateName');
        wire(btnUpdateName, "click", changeName);

        ko.applyBindings(this.model);
    };

    function changeName(event)
    {
        var firstName = document.getElementById('txtNewFirstName').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('txtNewLastName').value;

        this.model.friend.firstName = firstName;
        this.model.friend.lastName = lastName;
    };
};

var thisDocument = new ThisDocument();
thisDocument.init();
```

**Making the Model a Top-Level Object Inside Window**

If, however, I make the model a top-level member inside the `window` object, the code works fine and I get to know the answer to my question described in the HTML comments above and in the bullet point #2 above.

The answer is: no. Without having an observable, a simple `text:` binding does not update the view when the model changes.

Here is the code with the model as the top-level object:

**1a.js**

```
this.model = 
{
    friend : 
    {
        firstName : 'Sathyaish',
        lastName : 'Chakravarthy'
    }
};

var ThisDocument = function()
{
    this.init = function()
    {
        wire(window, "load", wireElementHandlers);
    };

    function wire(element, eventName, listener)
    {
        var ie = document.all ? true : false;

        if (!element) throw new Error("Element " + element + " not found.");

        if (ie)
        {
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, listener);
        }
        else
        {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, listener, false);
        }
    };


    function wireElementHandlers()
    {
        var btnUpdateName = document.getElementById('btnUpdateName');
        wire(btnUpdateName, "click", changeName);

        ko.applyBindings(model);
    };

    function changeName(event)
    {
        var firstName = document.getElementById('txtNewFirstName').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('txtNewLastName').value;

        model.friend.firstName = firstName;
        model.friend.lastName = lastName;
    };
};

var thisDocument = new ThisDocument();
thisDocument.init();
```

Therefore, my suspicion is that the `this` pointer is being messed up.

Is there an overload for the `applyBindings` method or may be another way if not an overload that allows me to tell knockout to use a particular object as the `this` parameter when binding a model?

For e.g.

```
var MyDocument = function()
{
  var model = 
  {
    friend : { firstName: 'Sathyaish', lastName: 'Chakravarthy' }
  };

  this.init : function()
  {
    ko.applyBindings(this.model /*, but this may lead knockout
    to not be able to discover my model, as my experience so far
    shows. I need to recalibrate the 'this' pointer so knockout
    knows to look for the model object inside whatever I tell it to, 
    i.e. inside an instance of the MyDocument class and not inside
    whatever the this pointer happens to reference when knockout 
    is performing the binding. */);
  };
}

var myDocument = new MyDocument();
myDocument.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need the mapping plugin and to change/put a value will need to do:

```
model.friend.firstName(firstName)
```

I will try your code later and if is necessary i will edit my answer.